# Android: is it possible to upload an image on a folder inside a server?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android. I'm building a drawing application for my project and I was wondering if you guys could give advice on my problem. This is my code.

**paintclass.java**

```
public class paintclass extends View {
    //InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.pic);

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    static Paint paint;
    static Path path = new Path();
    //private Paint cpaint;
    //private Path cpath = new Path();
    static int[] color = {255, 0, 0, 0};
    static int[] stroke = {5, 20};
    static boolean eraser = false;
    public LayoutParams params;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout parentLinearLayout2;
    LinearLayout ll;
    private Canvas mcanvas;
    private float mX, mY;

    public paintclass(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mcanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    public paintclass(Context context, AttributeSet a) {
        super(context, a);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mcanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setARGB(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        if (eraser == true) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke[1]);
        } else {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke[0]);
        }

        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        invalidate();
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        path.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mcanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        path.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  super.onTouchEvent(event);

        float a = event.getX();
        float b = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(a, b);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(a, b);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/liner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffcc"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff9900"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prima"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Temporary text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffcc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bl"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bl" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/r" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/b" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/y"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/y" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/o"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/o" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/g"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/g" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/p"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/p" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ad" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawingAre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.depictry.paintclass xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/draw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addsize"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minussize"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveimage"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
but[i] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveimage);
        but[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawingAre);
                ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prima);

                ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                ll.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll.getDrawingCache());
                ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                im.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        });
```

This code right here is where I want my image to be uploaded on a server folder, but all it does is display the image. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you want it to display then upload? or just upload ?

Comment: How does the server accept files? FTP? HTTP? SFTP? POST/GET? Any of these are possible to do, but each will require a different path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload image to a folder inside server.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138910/7060446) answer can help you.

Its uploadToServer class will be useful to you, just use path to folder on server.