# Receiving NullPointer when uploading file to PHP server - Android

Tags: android, image

I have an android app that crops an image and saves it to the phones internal directory. I then get the path name of the saved image and set it as an imageView so I know the path exists. But when I try to upload the file using a function I get the error NullPointerException.

**Here are the variables that I declare**

```
     private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

     private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
     private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
     private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

     ImageView imageView1;
     RoundImage roundedImage;
     Bitmap bitmap;
     ProgressDialog prgDialog;
     String encodedString;
     RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
     String imgPath, fileName;
     Bitmap bitmap2;
     TextView tv;
     String uploadFilePath;
     String uploadFileName;
     private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;

     //UPLOAD STUFF
     int serverResponseCode = 0;
     ProgressDialog dialog = null;

     String upLoadServerUri = null;
```

**Here is my onCreate()**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        //PHP UPLOAD PATH
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.waxjar.com/app_upload.php";



        //Camera Stuff

        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);

                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        //END CAMERA STUFF

         }// End OnCreate
```

**This is my onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");


                final String croppedfilepath = saveToInternalSorage(photo).toString();
                loadImageFromStorage(croppedfilepath);

                // UPLOAD STUFF
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                                 }
                             });                      

                          uploadFile(croppedfilepath);

                     }
                   }).start();

                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;

        }
    }
```

**Here is saveToInternalStorage()**

```
 private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.png");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

**Here is loadImageFromStorage()**

```
 private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        try {
            File f=new File(path, "profile.png");
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageBitmap(b);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Here is uploadFile()**

```
  public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       tv.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"; filename ="" + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.waxjar.com/uploadedimages/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                tv.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          tv.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(Main.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          tv.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }
```

How the process works is I take a picture with my camera or select it from the gallery. I then crop the image (I did not add the crop image function because I didn't think it was relevant). After it is cropped the image is saved using saveToInternalStorage() which is called in the function onActivityResult(). saveToInternalStorage() returns the path directory which I then used in the uploadFile() so it will upload the file but I get this logCat,

**LogCat**

```
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-53576
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052): Process: com.goboapp, PID: 26052
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052):    at com.goboapp.Main.uploadFile(Main.java:368)
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052):    at com.goboapp.Main$3.run(Main.java:222)
11-17 01:53:26.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26052):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: You can refer my Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android/20322851#20322851 It's pretty straight forward

Comment: Check whether your path name is correct or not.

Comment: I use the same path to upload the image as I do to set the image as an imageView so the path can't be null/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this AsyncTask for image upload.

```
public class SendFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    private Context conT;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String SendUrl = "";
    private String SendFile = "";
    private String Bilgiler = "";
    private String result;
    public File file;
    private int ProgressGoster=0;

    SendFile(Context activity, String url, String dosya, String Deger,int boyut,int gosteriyorum) {
        conT = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(conT);
        SendUrl = url;
        SendFile = dosya;
        Bilgiler = Deger;
        ProgressGoster = gosteriyorum;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        file = new File(SendFile);
        if(ProgressGoster==1){
            dialog.setMessage("Faks Gönderiliyor. Lütfen Bekleyiniz..");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax((int) file.length());
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****"
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 512;

        String[] q = SendFile.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            URL url = new URL(SendUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=dosya; filename=\""
                            + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpg" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
                    + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            int boyut = 0;
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                boyut += bytesRead;
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                if(ProgressGoster==1){
                    dialog.setProgress(boyut);
                }
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            String[] posts = Bilgiler.split("&");
            int max = posts.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                String[] kv = posts[i].split("=");
                outputStream
                        .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                                + kv[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"
                        + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(kv[1]);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            fileInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result1) {
        if(ProgressGoster==1){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do I put into the function when I call it? Example SendFile(WHAT GOES IN HERE?)

Comment: `ProgressGoster=1;
Dosya="";//--> this is your imagepath.
upLoadServerUri = ""; //--> upload url
FileSize = "" //-- your image file size if you want to use progress bar while uploading.
String FormData = "username=" + Session.getUsername()+ "&password=" + Session.getPassword(); //-- form data for user authentication
SendFile gonder = new SendFile(this, upLoadServerUri, Dosya,FormData,FileSize,ProgressGoster);
   gonder.execute();`