# How to upload image to server selected from gallery?

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am creating app where i need to add uploading image from gallery to server,I already aske this but did not get any answer,here it is [How to upload image from gallary to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539975/how-to-upload-image-from-gallary-to-server/27543200#27543200,the) problem is whenever I select from gallery and trying to send,it shows source file not exists,can any one help?

Comment: can u able to get the path/uri of the gallery file..?

Comment: yes i added one image in my emulator gallery service_lifecycle,but when i add apk in my cellphone and select picture from gallery it not uploading

Comment: what kind of error your getting..?

Comment: source file not exists

Comment: check this answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781831/android-upload-of-file-to-server

Comment: @RajeshMikkilineni i want to send image which i get from gallery to sever

Answer (score 1):

Start intent to select image file from gallery...

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),54);
```

On Activity Result get file URI...

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == 54 && resultCode != 0) {
                if (intent != null) {
                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Could not load image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Get file bytes from URI...

```
private byte[] GetFileBytes(Uri uri)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(200000);
    InputStream imageStream;
    try {
        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        byte[] buffer;
        buffer = new byte[100000];
        while ((imageStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Get MultipartEntity from byte array...

```
private MultipartEntity getEntity(byte[] bytes)
{
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ContentBody bin = new InputStreamBody(in, "Image_" + c.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
    entity.addPart("image_query_string_variable_name", bin);
}
```

MultipartEntity is a class of httpmime. You can find the JAR easily by Googling. You will need to add this jar file to your project from project properties.

Post to server...

```
private void PostData(MultipartEntity entity)
{
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();  
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 20000);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.you_server_url.com/someFileName.php");
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    //
    // Process the returned result from server...
    //
}
```

More Edit:

```
byte[] fileBytes = null;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == 54 && resultCode != 0) {
                if (intent != null) {
                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                    fileBytes = GetFileBytes(selectedImage);
                } else {
                    fileBytes = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Could not load image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// when button is clicked...
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(fileBytes != null)
    {
        MultipartEntity entity = getEntity(fileBytes);
        PostData(entity);
    }
}
```

Good Luck. :)

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: You can compare the code I posted here with your code ?!

Comment: suggest me what i should do

Comment: I don't want to live on this planet anymore. -_-

Comment: i will come to your funeral surely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67219/discussion-between-eddie-and-hemendra-sharma).