# In Android, is it possible to post an image to web-server without using MultipartEntity?

Tags: android, image, webserver, multipart

Please share, if its possible to post an image to web server without using MultipartEntity class.

Previously, i followed this tutorial https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/ for post an image in server. May i know possible ways to post image other than this method.

Comment: convert the image to a base64 string and post it

Comment: @Triode,Yes it is a alternative but have to scale large image before get Base64 String.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android

Comment: You did not tell why you don't wanna use MultipartEntity. It is deprecated now. You could use MultipartEntityBuilder. There still are other ways.

Comment: `Yes it is a alternative` ?? No that is no alternative as poster did not tell what to use instead of MultipartEntity. If one does not use MultipartEntity one could also better post the image not base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HttpURLConnection` you can directly write your data to the output stream.