# Upload image path to server android json

Tags: android, json, image, file

I have Tried lot of examples and watched many videos and done StackOverFlow, but i am not getting what i want.

1] I want to upload image path to server .
2] My php query required image of type FILE, So i cant send string. I need to upload image file path. I know how to send string and decode back to image.But i have no idea how to send image file path and then get back image.

Plz help me with this,I am in big trouble.

Things i have tried :

```
  private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 2;
    private String ImgPath = null;

    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

    private String encodedImage;

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //  onRegisterButtonClick();


                ImgPath = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                        PICK_FROM_FILE);



    }

 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "From Camera");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "From Gallery");
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {

            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            ImgPath = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); // from Gallery

            Log.d("image path", ImgPath.toString());

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImgPath, options);

            if (ImgPath == null) {
                ImgPath = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); // from File Manager
            }
            if (ImgPath != null) {
                // ivProfile.setImageBitmap(b);

                // rotate(ivProfile, 270);

                ExifInterface ei = null;
                try {
                    ei = new ExifInterface(ImgPath);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate(ivProfile, 180);
                        ivProfile.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(b, 180));

                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate(ivProfile, 270);
                        ivProfile.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(b, 270));

                        break;

                }

                try {
                    getBase64String(b);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 /*   Utils.showAlert(this, "Please select local gallery pics.",
                            false);*/
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {

            if (ImgPath == null) {
                ImgPath = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); // from File Manager

            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImgPath, options);

            if (ImgPath != null) {
                ivProfile.setImageBitmap(b);
                // rotate(ivProfile, 270);
                try {
                    getBase64String(b);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   // Utils.showAlert(mContext, "Out of memory", false);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap b, int orientation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return b;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return b;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                    b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            b.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return null;
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle() == "From Camera") {
            ImgPath = null;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            try {
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);
                this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (item.getTitle() == "From Gallery") {
            ImgPath = null;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                    PICK_FROM_FILE);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getBase64String(Bitmap path) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        path.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);

        byte[] biteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(biteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void rotate(View iv, float degree) {
        final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
        rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        iv.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
    }
```

and then i have set encodedImage to parameters and send it to server,But it is not working

Comment: What exactly issue I mean any error from server side or from client ..? If you got any error thn can you please post it...?

Comment: Please change the subject and the text of your post. You are noth trying to upload an image path. You are trying to upload an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTP mime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3) library(Preferable 4.3.3) and HTTP post to upload the file to the server.
The PHP server will recognize the image as FILE which is required in your case.
I have created a class which helps me to upload the image or any file to my server

```
public class FileUploadHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;
    private String URL;

    public FileUploadHelper(String URL) {
        multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            multipartEntity.addTextBody("<YOUR STRING KEY>", "<STRING VALUE>");

            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            HttpClient httpclient;
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addFile(String key, File newFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            multipartEntity.addBinaryBody(key, newFile);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No file was found at the path " + newFile.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

To use this class create Object of FileUploader class, then call its addFile() function and call execute() as this class extends AsyncTask.
In your code you already have File object as

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
```

Just pass this object to addFile().

Hope this will help you

Comment: @Lchigo Kurosaki .. Thank you..But i am not getting where to put all this thing.. can u plz explain ?

Comment: In your code try this, at onAcitivtyResult() you have code like ImgPath = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); // from Gallery.. I think it is the path of image you choose. At this you can call this asynctask as FileUploader abc = new FIleUploader("<Your url>"), then abc.addFile("string key",file object).. and then abc.execute()..

Comment: Sorry, but i m not getting things. If u have example it would be a great help

Comment: I have derived this answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android)