# Appium Android Jave - Parse Image by file path

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Parsing data from a spreadsheet. What would be the command for uploading an image by file path?

Comment: What exact problem are you facing and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey Ivan - I'm having a problem with where to even start. I'm pretty new to Java, even newer to Appium but I am trying to learn. What solutions do you maybe have in mind? Would SendKeys be something that would be able to facilitate an image by file path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want upload an image to server then you can follow this link:

[Uploading Images to Server android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android)

Comment: That's awesome, one way to do it. Thank you. Is there anyway to tell it to get the image by file path that I have on the spreadsheet?