# Create a post request mechanism with a file as an attachment

Tags: android

I need to create a post request mechanism that can send a file (a screenshot) from the android device to somewhere else. I am struggling to find a simple example that isn't outdated that can get me started to complete this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Images to Server android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android)

Comment: @TimCastelijns HttpPost and HttpClient do not work with android API 23. I think i need to use URLConnection but am still stuck.

Comment: use something else then. The internet is full of examples

Comment: I am looking my friend. I wouldn't be asking if I didn't spend a long time searching the web for help.

Comment: google "android network libraries" pick one you like then google "<library name> upload image to server"

Comment: Thank you @TimCastelijns. I will do that. This is all just very overwhelming and frustrating since I am very new to Android Studio and API's in general.

Comment: Best advice I can give is to take it slow. Don't try to do too many new things at a time, practice small bits and later on combine them