# Sending binary files jpg from android with Json Rest Services

Tags: java, android, json, rest, base64

I can't find a way to send binary file jpg with json Rest. The last one that I tried is with *Base64.encodeToString(byte[] array, Base64.DEFAULT)* and I expected in the server side with  *Base64.getDecoder().decode(String)*... yet no results. I have seen many posts, but nothing has helped. Can you suggest me any way or library.

I am using java with Eclipse. In the client side I use android.util.Base64 library, while in server side I use java.util.Base64.

The error that show me is this:

> Unexpected padding character ('=') as character #4 of 4-char base64
>   unit: padding only legal as 3rd or 4th character; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type byte[] from String

Comment: Could you give us more details on your server and application. Like the language you're using, libraries...

Comment: I am using java with eclipse. In the client side I use android.util.Base64 library, while in server side I use java.util.Base64. The error that show me is this: Unexpected padding character ('=') as character #4 of 4-char base64 unit: padding only legal as 3rd or 4th character; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse? The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported, as per this announcement in June 2015. https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt You must use Android Studio.

Comment: I know, but what to do... I have just come in the company and that's the way that they are working

Comment: You can Refer this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android