# How to upload all files of a folder to web server in Android?

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload all files of a folder to my PHP page.

That is, If I have several images inside a folder, and I want to upload (HTTP POST) all pictures in the folder to my PHP page, which then gets saved in my web directory by their respective file names.

How can I do that? I know about AsyncTask, but I am beginner in Android programming.
I don't know how to make array or list or loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Images to Server android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android)

Comment: @Shalu can you tell if this code is for uploading multiple images

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is way too older, I am not saying we should not implement but has to take care of a lot of things if implemented!

Rather go with implementing RxJava based implementation but again since you are new to the android programming, so I would not suggest!

Since you are new to the android programming so we can say it's a long problem to solve. I would suggest you go steps wise steps. Let me give you pointers you would be searching, exploring and building around:

- Find the directory in folders and iterate through each files to prepare a list
- Two popular ways of uploading images: 1) Convert into Base64 and upload one by one 2) Multipart image upload
- Instead of AsyncTask, you may use Retrofit Multipart image upload

Comment: Can you give the code for just second part - TO DO MULTIPART REQUEST.

Comment: Ready made code? That's not possible, did you check on Google? Lot of examples are available. Since you are a newbie in Android so I thought to saw you a direction.

Comment: Can't you provide link to those examples?