# Android Studio org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to post some data using volley to a server.

The issue seems to with an encoded string image.

On this line

```
 String name = namefield.getText().toString();
        String age = agefield.getText().toString();
        String gender = genderfield.getText().toString();
        String color = colorfield.getText().toString();
        String notes = notesfield.getText().toString();
        String images = encodeImage(bitmap);
        updatedetails(name, age, gender, color, notes, String.valueOf(owner), String.valueOf(id), images);
```

if I change image to empty string

```
        updatedetails(name, age, gender, color, notes, String.valueOf(owner), String.valueOf(id), "");
```

then than the data sends to server, which is how I know the image is the problem.

I logged the image response and this is what I get:

```
Strings: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
    AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
    AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAUAAk8DASIA
    AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
    AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
    ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
    p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
    AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
    BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
    U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
    uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+8LwX
    /wAit4a/7F/R/wD0011z/wCrH4/+hVyPgv8A5Fbw1/2L+j/+mmuuf/Vj8f8A0KuHC/7rP5f+knDh
    f91n8v8A0ksUUUV3HcFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQ
    AUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB
    RRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQBxPgv/kVvDX/AGL+j/8Apprr
    n/1Y/H/0KuR8F/8AIreGv+xf0f8A9NNdc/8Aqx+P/oVcOF/3Wfy/9JOHC/7rP5f+kliiivGvjx8b
    /hp+zT8FfiZ8f/i9r0Phn4afCrwrqfi/xnr/ANne7bT9G0bcZJUijDPPJu2RxRAbvOlALoA8g7ju
    PZaK/kXuv+Dkv9qeP4WN+3BpX/BGr4/XX/BN63vMf8NKXXxa8F6f49Phb+228PDxt/wqgeGWJ0Ft
    ebyvM/4S/wD4Qnacf8LBCjj9ovi3/wAFXv2NPhB/wTs0/wD4Kc33iq+1j9nzxN4P0TxH4Bg0vTGi
    8a+Ota8Q3baLoXgjRdIa9jWHxKNe/wCKevxcgJ4YbTPEDXFwYbeVyAfqNRX8pnhf/g4t+MPw/wBf
    +C3jj9vr/gmB8Yv2Mf2R/wBpLXNJ0b4O/tM6p8SNG8Zafobay8lxouu/FjwZL4N8LzeGIbiN18Ry
    gFrq1sHSWytvEYhM6/0IfHr9sT9lr9l61+Gd9+0H8cfAfwpsfi94t0zwV8L7vxVrQsP+E28U6v8A
    NFo+jDOdziWNyzP5aqw3uHIVgD6jor8ov+Cn3/BVD4P/APBMz4d/Du41nwX4r+Nnxv8Ajz4qb4ef
    s8/ALwBNGnjP4oeLY/7IilB1gLP/AGFodr/bOk+f4heO5Y3Gr2tta2VxfMYa+Lv2W/8AguD8Rtf/
    AGvfhp+wt/wUd/YO8f8A/BP/AONnx509dc/Z/uPEPxC0P4jeCPiYTczSR+H/AO2/Dnh6x/4R7xDE
    sPlb1aeJ/FiLaagvhqZ4wQD+i6ivwy/4KV/8Ff8AxP8AsI/tP/s6/sd/CX9in4jftm/GX9obwH4s
    +IPhvwj8M/iDo/hjW7HSvBeszxM8ek6x4V8VHV52i0bW7ppDJDIkekOEYSFVrX/Y3/4KR/tyftJ/
    H3wx8I/jd/wR+/aQ/ZH8Aa9o/im+1v44fEXx/oXiDwtoOp6HoT63oeivosXhKBh/wlZWXw8HSdWj
    uJhIrMEMaAH7bUUV8u/tNftgfstfsb+Arr4i/tQfHjwH8FfCkHmR2l5401yOw1HWZeUMOgaGpbxF
    4jmjcEpH4Zt7hyzENgA4APqKivx0/Yw/4LF/AT9vP9qv4mfs0/Br4M/tGaBF4E+FOifGGx+LXxU+
    GT/Dvwr4u8H6/wCIYfDujaxomg6/cf8ACxNDg8UGSW78ETeMvCPhyTxPa6RdvbRhcbv2LoAKKKKA
    CiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAK
    KKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKrySwwxmadhCB1LHodzYHGc5xnoeGGepNAFiivLviX8
    SLf4ceGI/EI09tZ8+7js7W2tbkKJC3mYIY5DY2EHGNrEjdnit/wL4nt/GvhXSPFMFo9jDqlp5gtH
    wSoLEAZAHGQ2B1AYqScE0AdlRX5If8FKf+Cy/wCw5/wSy0Cy/wCGh/iBqWsfE/XtHfV/BvwK8AWR
    8SfErxBp2bkLq/lGaDQ/D+gI1q4HiHxVcW4l3gQPPIXjH82Fz/wdmft5/Fi8uPFv7KP/AARx8eeO
    PhVbsr2/iGc/Gz4haheafueN2Ot/Dz4X/wDCOaFuADMDJcLtKYcsuaAP7vqK/kA/Yz/4O6P2Q/in
    46j+En7cfwL+IP7EPj6W7h0dtf1/UtY8b/DSw1MB4wNfd/DXhHxR4C+VWZ5JvCkqCUxLJcRu4cf1
    p+Htf0PxToWk+I/DGpadrega3Zafq2ka9pV6moaVq2mawoaDU9I1aKV1kSRH3qUY5jMeCN+QAbcQ
    JVgIvL6ZG8Pnlsck8Y6++7H8OS8LtUjpnHHXODzzk4x19+nPWvjX4g/HrxhpnivxF4L+GHhPwtqR
    8DNo6ePfFfj/AMWjw/4X0bVdat5tV0TRNLjgWbWtb1maNVZ1SOC3jZo0LCVkB5vS/jR+0r4ivINL
    0jS/2YtVvZQS1va/Enx074AZshIvCm48LxtUkjB5ywr4rE8WcGZXm9LhrMeMOE8oz+VODhwzV4qw
    9DEuMnNr93N0qlJrm1h7NST0nBSTUurD5bmuKwdTG4bLpckUuf3oaW5m2256x1unKSdrtJ3cj78o
    r5J/t/8Abj/6Jp+zz/4cDx1/8y1H9v8A7cf/AETT9nn/AMOB46/+ZavtTlPraivnf4Q/FbXfGmt+
    MfAPxA8GHwH8Q/A1npF/rOk2urrrvh2+0vXGuBoetaPrXlx70P8AZLK0MqLLFIGZg0jOR9EUAFFF
    FAHE+C/+RW8Nf9i/o/8A6aa65/8AVj8f/Qq5HwX/AMit4a/7F/R//TTXXP8A6sfj/wChVw4X/dZ/
    L/0k4cL/ALrP5f8ApJYryz4p/Cf4WfHL4c+K/hT8ZfA3hz4j/DjxjY/2b4w8E+K9Ii1Tw1renGUa
    o0OsaPcKysDLGrEP87TFC6szmOvU6+Wv2wPCn7R3jv8AZf8AjV4I/ZI+IHg74Y/tE+J/B9/pHwk+
    IPjizEvhrwh4r1FmB13XIf8AhFfGDEQaMdRMf/FK3UgumjZUSRVlHcdx/Or/AMFfv2ntN+Ivh6D/
    AIN6f+CV3ws8N+LPj58VvCWk/Dz4p2XhbTY7D4PfsffAG3fSNY1ttdIUeH9A1658Py5twhL+DoZA
    yAfEifwPBXxB/wAF3f2U9B/Yk/4J4f8ABDn9huLxBc+Ivg78O/2wPAXgr4la9eLDpum+LNRJn1jW
    tZ1qONtqxzHXfHM0ZbDojudqvH5VeifsXf8ABGf/AIOKP2B7D4myfs//ALX3/BOa18V/F7xXqPjL
    4mfE/wAceFPin8RPi1441WSSWTGu+OPEn7P7+ILi3eWSSYWyMoS4lMrSedtdv2
```

while the other data response are normal like:

```
Strings: red
```

The logcat says the problem is here:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.i("Check", result);
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
public void updatedetails(final String name, final String age, final String gender, final String color, final String notes, final String owner, final String id, final String pet_image) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating pet details");
        progressDialog.show();
        try {
            String url = "https://happy-paws.co.za/dogwalking/apis/v1/pet/update_pet.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            String result = response.toString();
//                            Log.d("zzzz","res "+result);
                            Toast.makeText(update.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getDataResponse1(result);
                            Log.i("Check", result);
                            Log.i("Check", response);



                        }
                    },
                    new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(update.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage());


                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                    String str = "{\"name\":\"" + name + "\",\"age\":\"" + age + "\",\"gender\":\"" + gender + "\",\"color\":\"" + color + "\",\"notes\":\"" + notes + "\",\"owner\":\"" + owner + "\",\"id\":\"" + id + "\",\"pet_image\":\"" + pet_image + "\"}";
                    return str.getBytes();
                }


                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

//                    params.put("email",email);
//                    params.put("password",password);
                    return params;
                }

            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //App.handleUncaughtException(e);
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void getDataResponse1(String result) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
        progressDialog.show();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.i("Check", result);
            JSONObject current = jsonObject.getJSONObject(result);
            String message = current.getString("message");
            String name = jsonObject.isNull("name") ? null : jsonObject.getString("name");
            String age = jsonObject.isNull("age") ? null : jsonObject.getString("age");
            String gender = jsonObject.isNull("gender") ? null : jsonObject.getString("gender");
            String notes = jsonObject.isNull("notes") ? null : jsonObject.getString("notes");
            String color = jsonObject.isNull("color") ? null : jsonObject.getString("color");
//            String android_status=jsonObject.getString("android_status");
            if (message.equals("Pet was updated.")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                updatedetails(name, age, gender, color, notes, String.valueOf(owner), String.valueOf(id), pet_image);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void selectImage(Context context) {
        final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Choose your profile picture");

        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        profilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        encodeImage(bitmap);

                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        try {

                            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            profilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            encodeImage(bitmap);
//                            Glide.clear(profilepic);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


                            Toast.makeText(update.this, "Pet added succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ba);
        byte[] imagebyte = ba.toByteArray();
        encode = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imagebyte, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encode;
    }
```

And then where I submit:

```
        updatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        String name = namefield.getText().toString();
        String age = agefield.getText().toString();
        String gender = genderfield.getText().toString();
        String color = colorfield.getText().toString();
        String notes = notesfield.getText().toString();
        String images = encodeImage(bitmap);
        updatedetails(name, age, gender, color, notes, String.valueOf(owner), String.valueOf(id), images);
        Log.d("Strings",images );
       Log.d("Strings",color );
```

Comment: what is your data type for image on database server??

Answer (score 1):

image response is ok. you must set image data type as LONGTEXT or LONGBLOB on database server. but a better solution is to use Multipart Image Upload for upload image on server.
you can try with [Uploading Images to Server android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android)