# How to send image url to server as multipart?

Tags: android, retrofit, uri, multipart

I am getting the image URL from the backend as a string URL and now I need to send it again to the server, I am getting an error while converting it to multipart and Uri

```
            File file = null;
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Photo1");
            file.createNewFile();


            InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri1);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream );



            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , bos); // YOU can also save it in JPEG
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            parts1 =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Photo1", file.getName(), requestBody);
            Log.d("@@parts1", String.valueOf(parts1));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("@@IOException", e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am getting an error

```
D/@@IOException: No content provider: http://anothercz.yilstaging.com/writable/uploads/20210107/1610027045_73aae04fa7f668e42a12.png
```

please help me how to resolve it, I would Appreciate every answer

Comment: getting error in this line     InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri1);

Comment: try with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322528/uploading-images-to-server-android

Comment: You cannot use a http:// protocol there to open an input stream. As the message tells you that would need a content:// provider protocol.

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with sending something to a server. Only with opening a stream.

Comment: BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) binding.imgUserCircleFirst.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

Comment: finally, i got solution